# Converter formatos de divisas EUR->USA e USA->EUR no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

O meu problema: Converter um Range Excel com formato de divisas (USD) em (EUR) e vice versa.

> Formato USD 123,456,789.00
>
> Formato EUR 123 456 789,00

Tentei codificar uma substituição em VBA mas sou um novato nestas coisas.

Alguém pode ajudar a codificar uma macro ou função em Excel que resolva esta situação?

Answer (score 1):

Seria um replace normal, tipo retirando as virgulas e colocando espaços; E retirando os pontos e colocando virgulas?
O formato da célula está em texto ou numero?
Se quiser se repetir, é só colocar um loop até o final, qualquer coisa edite sua perguntas com informações adicionais.

bom, tente isso:

```
 Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Cells.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```